# Usage and grammar of that

Tags: grammar, word-usage, that

I googled about usage and grammar of that. There are several usages
First, as an objective. For example, I think that it is not a good idea. 
Second, as a subjective, such as That he choose to take a bus to work is not a good idea. 
Third, as an extension after an adjective, such as I am glad that he survived the situation. 
Forth, as an extension of it, such as it is a good idea that voting is compulsory in australia. 
Firth, the usage of so...that and such....that. I am so happy that he survived the storm. Voting is a good idea that everyone has a say.

However, my question is that can one use that after a noun to explain more?

For example, I am a fool that I lost my key and got myself locked outside my door. Voting is a good idea that everyone has a say.

Comment: The subordinator "that" introduces relative clauses as well as content clauses (the default kind of finite subordinate clause that you have in mind). It's meaningless, serving simply as a marker of subordination, so it's neither subjective nor objective. Content clauses mostly function as complement of a verb, adjective, preposition or noun, where they expand the meaning of the item they complement.

Comment: 'I am a fool that I lost my key' sounds as if it might have been acceptable in Shakespeare's day. 'I am a fool in that I lost my key' is grammatically acceptable but in a rarefied register (ie almost nobody would speak like this).

Comment: Thus you made a fool of yourself or became a fool. The 'that clause' is a delayed appositive of *I*.

Comment: No, only noun phrases can be appositives.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> The subordinator "that" introduces relative clauses as well as content clauses (the default kind of finite subordinate clause that you have in mind). It's meaningless, serving simply as a marker of subordination, so it's neither subjective nor objective. Content clauses mostly function as complement of a verb, adjective, preposition or noun, where they expand the meaning of the item they complement.